# How do I save a txt file for each set of links?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape multiple pages of Yellow Pages and store the printout in a txt file.I know that a login is not required to get the data on these pages, I am just trying to get a little practice logging in with requests.Session().

I want to store the titles of each url in set_1 in a txt file, YP_set_1.txt. And the same for the url's in set_2.

This is my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests.cookies
import time



s = requests.Session()

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36',
           'Referer': "https://accounts.yellowpages.com/login?next=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.yellowpages.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth&client_id=590d26ff-34f1-447e-ace1-97d075dd7421&response_type=code&app_id=WEB&source=ypu_login&vrid=63dbd394-afff-4794-aeb0-51dd19957ebc&merge_history=true"}

url = "https://accounts.yellowpages.com/login?next=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.yellowpages.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth&client_id=590d26ff-34f1-447e-ace1-97d075dd7421&response_type=code&app_id=WEB&source=ypu_register&vrid=cc9cb936-50d8-493b-83c6-842ec2f068ed&register=true"
r = s.get(url).content
page = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
soup.prettify()

csrf = soup.find("input", value=True)["value"]

USERNAME = '****.*****@*****.***'
PASSWORD = '*******'

cj = s.cookies
requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(cj)

login_data = dict(email=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD, _csrf=csrf)

s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)

set_1 = "This is the first set."

targeted_pages = ['https://www.yellowpages.com/brookfield-wi/business',
                  'https://www.yellowpages.com/bronx-ny/cheap-party-halls',
                  'https://www.yellowpages.com/bronx-ny/24-hour-liquor-store',
                  'https://www.yellowpages.com/bronx-ny/24-hour-oil-change',
                  'https://www.yellowpages.com/bronx-ny/auto-insurance',
                  'https://www.yellowpages.com/bronx-ny/awnings-canopies',
                  'https://www.yellowpages.com/bronx-ny/golden-corral',
                  'https://www.yellowpages.com/bronx-ny/concrete-contractors',
                  'https://www.yellowpages.com/bronx-ny/automobile-salvage',
                  'https://www.yellowpages.com/bronx-ny/24-hour-daycare-centers',
                  'https://www.yellowpages.com/bronx-ny/movers',
                  'https://www.yellowpages.com/bronx-ny/nursing-homes',
                  'https://www.yellowpages.com/bronx-ny/signs'
                  ]
for target_urls in targeted_pages:
    targeted_page = s.get(target_urls, headers=headers, cookies=cj)
    targeted_soup = BeautifulSoup(targeted_page.content, "lxml")

    for record in targeted_soup.findAll('title'):
        with open("YP_Set_1.txt", "w") as text_file:
            print(set_1 + '\n' + record.text, file=text_file)
time.sleep(5)

set_2 = "This is the second set."

targeted_pages_2 = ['https://www.yellowpages.com/north-miami-beach-fl/attorneys',
                    'https://www.yellowpages.com/north-miami-beach-fl/employment-agencies',
                    'https://www.yellowpages.com/north-miami-beach-fl/dentists',
                    'https://www.yellowpages.com/north-miami-beach-fl/general-contractors',
                    'https://www.yellowpages.com/north-miami-beach-fl/electricians',
                    'https://www.yellowpages.com/north-miami-beach-fl/pawnbrokers',
                    'https://www.yellowpages.com/north-miami-beach-fl/lighting-fixtures',
                    'https://www.yellowpages.com/north-miami-beach-fl/towing'
                    ]
for target_urls_2 in targeted_pages_2:
    targeted_page_2 = s.get(target_urls_2, headers=headers, cookies=cj)
    targeted_soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(targeted_page_2.content, "lxml")

    for record in targeted_soup_2.findAll('title'):
        with open("YP_Set_2.txt", "w") as text_file:
            print(set_2 + '\n' + record.text, file=text_file)
```

When I run the code though, this is the print out for YP_Set_1.txt.

```
This is the first set.
Signs in Bronx, New York with Reviews & Ratings - YP.com
```

Printout for YP_Set_2.txt.

```
This is the second set.
Towing in North Miami Beach, Florida with Reviews & Ratings - YP.com
```

Is there a quick fix that will enable me to store all of the titles for each url in the set in the text files instead of just grabbing the title of the last url in the set? Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep opening the file in the loop so you keep overwriting the content, you could keep reopening using `"a"` for append in place of `"w"` which overwrites but it is easier to just  open once outside the loops:

```
with open("YP_Set_2.txt", "w") as text_file:
    for target_urls_2 in targeted_pages_2:
        targeted_page_2 = s.get(target_urls_2, headers=headers, cookies=cj)
        targeted_soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(targeted_page_2.content, "lxml")

        for record in targeted_soup_2.find_all('title'):            
                text_file.write(set_2 + '\n' + record.text)
```

Do the same for both blocks.

Comment: Appreciate the help from you once again.